# Finnish language is not in list for available spell checking languages in Libreoffice

Tags: fedora, language, libreoffice, spell-check

Finnish language is not in the list for available spell checking languages in Libreoffice. 
Steps to reproduce the problem: install Fedora 29 or 30, libreoffice 6.2.3.2 and libreoffice-voikko -language pack. The place where "Finnish" should be found is: Libreoffice Writer -> Tools -> Spelling -> Text language.
Choosing document defaut language to Finnish does not add it to that list. As comparison this works in Debian 9 without a problem.

This guestion was first asked and solved in old Ask Fedora -site (https://askbot.fedoraproject.org). Google Search does not find guestions and answers from there anymore (at least for me) so it is almost as it was erased from the internet. Therefore in order to let the resolution to be available for Fedora users, I'll ask it again here with the resolution.

Comment: AskFedora has moved to a new platform at http://ask.fedoraproject.org

Comment: It seems to me that old Q&A's can't be found on the new site.

Comment: Which they say at the website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the Fedora 29 and 30 packaging of libreoffice-voikko is broken. The python files under the extension should be located under a subdirectory called pythonpath.

You can verify this issue by exporting PYUNO_LOGLEVEL=ARGS to your environment and running soffice --writer from a console.

Also, you can work around the problem by moving the related .py files under the pythonpath directory (for example on x86_64 as root):

```
cd /usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/extensions/voikko.uno.pkg
mkdir pythonpath
mv GrammarChecker.py PossibleHyphens.py SpellAlternatives.py HyphenatedWord.py PropertyManager.py SpellChecker.py Hyphenator.py SettingsEventHandler.py VoikkoHandlePool.py pythonpath
```